# Как указать свой конфиг для nginx в Docker

Tags: yii2, nginx, docker, docker-compose

Осваиваю docker.

**Столкнулся с такой проблемой:** 
не могу понять как заменить `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` на свой конфиг ?
Или быть может я в корни неправильно делаю...

Алгоритм запуска и развертывания yii2-приложения в docker.

1. `composer create-project --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced apptest`
2. по умолчанию в **apptest/frontend/Dokerfile** следующий код 
   `FROM yiisoftware/yii2-php:7.4-apache` , 
   который я меняю на `FROM nginx`
3. **docker-compose.yml** 
   добавляю `nginx: image:nginx ports: "8080"` и в `volumes`,
   я так понимаю, нужно указать путь на свой конфиг
   (в данном примере нужный конфиг `apptest/nginx/my.conf`).

Несколько часов уже не могу разобраться.

```
version: '3.2'

services:

  nginx:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/my.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf



  frontend:
    build: frontend
    ports:
      - 20080:80
    volumes:
      # Re-use local composer cache via host-volume
      - ~/.composer-docker/cache:/root/.composer/cache:delegated
      # Mount source-code for development
      - ./:/app

  backend:
    build: backend
    ports:
      - 21080:80
    volumes:
      # Re-use local composer cache via host-volume
      - ~/.composer-docker/cache:/root/.composer/cache:delegated
      # Mount source-code for development
      - ./:/app

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=verysecret
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=yii2advanced
      - MYSQL_USER=yii2advanced
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret
```

Answer (score 0):

**Вам нужны контейнеры:**

1. nginx
2. php-fpm
3. mysql

В nginx пропишите location для фронта и бэка и проксирование на php.